# Is my proof that subset {$u_1....u_p$} in $V$ is linearly independent IFF {$[u_1]_B...[u_p]_B$} is linearly independent in $ℝ^{n}$ valid?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Please verify and provide feedback on my solution for the following exercise.

- This question concerns a vector space $V$, a basis $B=$
  {$b_1...b_n$}, and a coordinate mapping $x↦[x]_B$.

  Prove that a subset {$u_1....u_p$} in $V$ is linearly independent if
  and only if the set of coordinate vectors {$[u_1]_B...[u_p]_B$} is
  linearly independent in $ℝ^{n}$.
  $$$$

Proof:

If {$u_1....u_p$}  $∈V$ is linearly independent, then scalars $c_1....c_p∈ℝ$ satisfying $c_1u_1+....+c_pu_p=0$ must all be $0$. Because $u↦[u]_B$ is a linear map we can write $[c_1u_1+....+c_pu_p]_B$$=$  $c_1[u_1]_B+....+c_p[u_p]_B$$=[0]_b=0$ with $c_1....c_p$ still all zero, and thus {$[u_1]_B...[u_p]_B$} is linearly independent.

Now I will prove the other direction.

Now, $x↦[x]_B$ is both an isomorphism and a linear map and so $[x]_B↦x$ is also an isomorphism and therefore  one to one. If {$[u_1]_B...[u_p]_B$} is linearaly independent then $c_1[u_1]_B+....+c_p[u_p]_B$$=[0]_b=0$ implies that $c_1....c_p$ are all equal to $0$. But because this mapping is one to one, $[u_1]_B=u_1.....[u_p]_B=u_p$. Thus we can write $c_1u_1+....+c_pu_p$$=0$ with $c_1...c_p$ still all zero, and this proves that {$u_1.....u_p$} are linearly independent.

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's ok.  What it boils down to is that the mapping is just a change of basis, and hence an isomorphism.  Linearly independent sets correspond to linearly independent sets under isomorphisms.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am supposed to be very specific about stuff because I am new. Is there anything at all that might make it an invalid proof?

Comment: All I can come up with is that it seems a little redundant.  Both directions are essentially the same, since you have an isomorphism.  So it seems like you could sort of "cut it in half", or, do it all at once.  Other than that good job.  Oh yeah, I think you  need injectivity in both directions.  You may have left that out of the first part.

Comment: thanks again for the response, can you briefly explain why I need injectivity in the first direction?  i have linearity.

Comment: sure.  well, if you don't have it, then perhaps $c_1u_1+\dots+c_pu_p\ne0$.

Comment: Ahh, I got a little confused.  It's a little hard to tell which direction is which.  At least for me.

Comment: (I would say) just be careful that you start with the vectors you want to be linearly independent, then prove the only linear combination which is zero is the trivial one.  I got thrown off a bit by you restating the definition for the domain space.

Comment: Here's how the first direction should go:  suppose that $c_1[u_1]_\beta+\dots+c_p[u_p]_\beta=0$.  Then it follows, by injectivity and linearity, that $c_1u_1+\dots+c_pu_p=0$.  Then since $\{u_1,\dots,u_p\}$ are linearly independent, you can conclude that all the $c_i$ equal zero.

Comment: that is a lot better